# Is there a simple script to duplicate files into a new folder based on a csv file?

Tags: macos, automation

Our challenge is that we need to search and duplicate approx 3000 images into a new folder.

The list of image names is a csv file. The files are all on one drive, but in many different folders.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the cvs file (just a few lines)?

Answer (score 3):

Using Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /path/to/file.csv | while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3
do
    find . -path "$col1" -exec cp {} /DESIRED/DIRECTORY \;
done
```

- `IFS` is the input field separator. Declare as `,` for `.csv`.
- `find . -path` searches through your home directory recursively for names
  read from `col1`, returning the full path.
- `exec` executes the `cp` command on `{}`, which represents all the results `find` returns
- the files are copied to `/DESIRED/DIRECTORY` and `\;` is required for terminating the `exec` command

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple python script that will do the trick:

```
import csv, subprocess

csv_path = '/Users/mdryden/Desktop/test2/test.csv'
search_path = '/Users/mdryden/Desktop/test2/'
output_path = '/Users/mdryden/Desktop/test3/'

with open(csv_path, 'rb') as csvfile:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
    csvfile.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
    for line in reader:
        subprocess.call(["find", search_path, "-name", line[0],
                        "-exec", "cp", "{}", output_path,";"])
```

Set csv_path, search_path, and output_path accordingly. It it's any sort of remotely standard CSV format, it should be able to autodetect it.The CSV should have no header rows and you need to set `line[0]` to the number of the column containing the file names (starting at 0 for the first column).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [applescript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html).

Open the csv file in excel grab the files, then pass the variable to the terminal where you would execute a `find` command followed by a `copy` command to the directory of your choice.

Here is some pointers:

- [Executing commands](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5105/10733) from applescript;
- How to [open an excel file from the command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/127297/10733) line, and
- [Open a file in applescript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/15690/10733).

Loop through the csv.